# VSCode debugger: set a breakpoint in a Typescript package symlinked with `npm link`

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, source-maps, npm-link

I'm trying to debug a NodeJS app and its related typescript packages linked with `npm link`.

Structure looks like this:

```
/root/package-a # typescript package
/root/package-b # another typescript package
/root/app # NodeJS application
```

I have linked the packages to the app as such:

1. `npm link` inside each package
2. `npm link package-a package-b`  in the app

And then in `/root/app/.vscode/launch.json` I have:

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks"],
"outFiles": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/build/**/*.js",
  "${workspaceFolder}/../package-a/build/**/*.js",
  "${workspaceFolder}/../package-b/build/**/*.js",
]
```

This all works very well when it comes to building  each package and the app with `npm run tsc` . Also in watch mode, changes are correctly propagated from packages to app. However when I try to set a breakpoint in VS Code inside any of the packages, the debugger can't find the related TS source. The breakpoint stays grey :-(

[image: The red breakpoints are in the app, while the grey breakpoint is inside a package]

Also: I've setup each `tsconfig.json` with `"sourceMap": true`, so there are `.js.map` files next to each built files in the app and in the packages.

How to correctly set this up so that the breakpoint in packages turn red ?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same setup and problem

Comment: Haven't fixed it yet. I'm still very looking forward to hear about a solution. Anyone ?

Comment: @Ben , [Me to have this problem now for 2 weeks I have tried everything next up is reinstalling laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136755/cant-set-breakpoints-on-npm-linked-library)

Answer (score 0):

1. the launch.json should not has both the runtimeArgs and the outFiles. it should look like this:

   ```
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "name": "Launch event",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/services/event/src/start.ts",
      "outputCapture": "std",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/services/event/.env"
    }
   ```

   ]
   }
2. make sure vscode symlink icon is displayed (logger) (in the lib you symlinked) : [image]
3. to symlink you can also (logger) :

[image]

4. most important: you should build the npm (in the example - logger), after you build it make sure to go to the node_modules of the service (or root) and see that your changes are built and can be found inside the node_modules (the symlike should take care of it)
5. 

[image]